# Nginx redirect traffic to ilo

Tags: nginx, redirect, hp-proliant, ilo

I have a hp proliant server with ilo and a nginx server.
To reach ilo from outside the router I use port 81 and 444 because 80 and 443 are already taken by nginx.

But is there a way that I can somehow redirect the trafic(of a certain domain e.g. ilo.example.com) via nginx to my ilo IP?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP iLO is an [out-of-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) server control interface which is used to control the server even when the OS that is installed on it is offline, or completely damages/uninstalled. For this to implement, it has a separate IP address, and, if installed properly, a separate LAN port (*shared* mode, when it's connected through the OS interfaces is available, but it's a source of many problems). This also means that it has it's own network controller and it's own IP address, so saying *80 and 443 are already taken by nginx* you cannot be more wrong, because either your iLO is misconfigured and thus not working, either iLO and your OS have completely different IP addresses and probably VLANs.

Comment: With "Already taken" I mean that I can't portforwart a port to multiple IPs. But I didn't thought about when the server is off...

Comment: You shouldn't portforward anything. You should use plain network setup and public IPs when you need them. Or VPN when you don't. NAT with a numerous portforwards is a clear sign of misdesigned network.

Comment: And, after all, you can have a publicly accessible WAN VLAN attached to the iLO port.

Comment: It's probably a dedicated or co-located server with a single IP allotment.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't the right way to handle ILO access.** 
*(Do you NEED a public DNS entry for your ILO?)*

It should be behind a VPN, if possible. Maybe static NAT if you have the capability and IP space...

However, on the ILO side, the port settings are fully configurable.

[image]